# Classification of finitely generated bimodules over "skew PID"s?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

Let R be a noncommutative ring with a 1 and no zero divisors, such that all (two-sided) ideals of R are principally generated.  Is there a classification theorem for finitely generated bimodules over R?  What if we strengthen the condition to all (two-sided) ideals of R are principally generated by an element of the center of R?

Comment: I assume "principally generated" means that the ideal $I$ is $RaR$ for some $a/in R$? This theorem would presumably generalize a theorem about (commutative) PIDs, which would in turn generalize a theorem about (commutative fields. Do you know a classification theorem for f.g. bimodules over a field?

Comment: The definition is $I$ is the intersection of all ideals that $a$ is a member of, for some $a\in R$, which I think comes out to $RaR+RaR+...+RaR$. Also, I don't, although the first thing that comes to mind is that if the field $F$ is a prime field, then they are all isomorphic to exactly one of $\{F^0,F^1,F^2,F^3,...\}$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by RaR. 

Comment: An $R$-bimodule is the same as a module for $R\otimes R$. If $F$ is a field transcendental over the prime field then $F\otimes F$ is a pretty complicated ring.

Comment: Sorry, this is definitely not the point of the question but: is it really a good idea to describe a noncommutative ring all of whose two-sided ideals are principal as a "skew PID"?  This for instance makes every simple algebra into a skew PID.  I would have rather thought that the correct analogues were left-PIDs and right-PIDs.  Or am I mistaken?  (I am shaky on noncommutative rings, although I have some motivations to learn.)

Comment: Tom, wouldn't it be $R\otimes \operatorname{op}(R)$, ie the opposite ring?
Pete, do all simple algebras have no zero divisors?  If yes, then perhaps a better term for what I was describing would be two-sided-PIDs.

Comment: @Ricky: no, e.g. matrix algebras have zero divisors.  